# How to list files which are not in another branch using git?

Tags: git, git-diff

I have two branches master and develop. master has been recently merged into develop. Develop has some extra code which is not in master. How do I see which files exist only in develop and not in master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `develop` branch : `git diff master`

Or for only files that will be added (new files): `git diff master --diff-filter=A`